# Covariance and Correlation by indicator method.

Tags: probability, statistics

A question for the interview. An urn contains 90 marbles, of which there are 20 green, 20 black, and 50 red marbles. Tom draws 10 marbles without replacement, and Jerry draws 10 marbles without replacement. Let Y = # of green marbles Tom gets, and Z= # of green marbles Jerry gets. What are the numerical values for Corr(Y, Z) and Cov(Y, Z)?
This is my answer:
I've found E(Y) and E(Z) by using Hypergeometric. I got E(Y) = 10.20/90 = 20/9 and E(Z) is same as E(Y). But tell me that how can I find E(Y^2)
and E(Z^2) and E(YZ)? Because I've to calculate Corr(Y, Z) and Cov(Y, Z).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've to find Corr(Y, Z) and Cov(Y, Z). So can you explain me in detail how can I find that? please?